# SSH connection freezes periodically

Tags: ssh

I'm seeing weird freezes when I'm connected to my server (Debian 11) with SSH. My typing stops getting to the server after a while, and after a minute or couple, all my key strokes are applied. So, they are buffered somewhere and applied after a while. This happens really frequently and it is difficulty to get anything done.

Very much appreciated if someone can provide any ideas why this happens and how to debug it.

When the freeze happens, I can open another SSH session to the same server and it works, until it freezes the same way. So, it is not the internet connection that is lost.

My /etc/ssh/ssh_config (/etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/ is empty)

```
Include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf

Host *
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    ServerAliveInterval 100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to fix this on RHEL 7.9 we are use to add the following in sshd_config :

```
UseDNS no
```

Comment: Thank you! After this change I did not get any freezes.

Comment: @mika can you edit your question in order to provide some insight about the distrib you are using ? Thanks

Comment: Why does this help?